How to Integrate Alternative Payment Solutions with Next.js & Payload CMS (Tunisia: No Stripe/PayPal Support)
I’m working on an e-commerce project using Next.js for the frontend and Payload CMS for the backend. The problem is that Stripe and PayPal are not supported in my country (Tunisia).
Instead, we use payment gateways like:

Clicktopay (from an enterprise called the Service Monétique)
Flouci, an e-wallet that offers an API.

What I’ve Done:

I’ve searched through Payload CMS’s GitHub Discussions and found some mentions of integrating alternative payment methods, but there is no clear, easy-to-follow solution available for a beginner like myself.

I’ve looked into the documentation for both Clicktopay and Flouci, but I’m unsure how to properly integrate them, especially with Payload CMS, which is designed around Stripe.

Before attempting to implement this on my own, I want to reach out to the community for advice on the best approach.


My Questions:

Has anyone successfully integrated Clicktopay or Flouci (or any standard solution for another way of payment!) with Next.js or Payload CMS?

Is there any guidance on building a custom payment plugin for Payload CMS, or should I handle payments directly from Next.js?

Are there any libraries, tutorials, or existing solutions I can use to simplify this process?


I’m relatively new to backend and plugin development, so any help would be appreciated!
